# openCV:capture images from webcam but only greysreen

Tags: opencv

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? I can use my webcam by other code, so there is nothing do with the supported problem. In my code below, I must set the camera index into a loop so that i can motivate my camera(the led inductor is on, simply set "CvCapture* camera=cvCaptureFromCAM(0)" can not run! that's wierd!).However, I just can obtain a greysreen,why?

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"

int main(int grac, char** grav)
{
    CvCapture* camera;
    int index;
    for (index = -1; index <1; index++)
    {
        camera = cvCaptureFromCAM(index);
        if (camera)
        {
            printf("%d\n", index);
            IplImage* f;
            cvNamedWindow("camera", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
            while (1)
            {
                f = cvQueryFrame(camera);
                cvShowImage("camera", f);
                char c = cvWaitKey(33);
                if (c == 27)break;
            }
        }
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
    cvDestroyAllWindows;
}
```

Comment: _Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?_ Well, first you shouldn't use obsolete C syntax, but use C++ syntax!

Comment: You are right, now i use C++ and everything go smoothly! Thanks!